# what in/out bound mail system to use ? hosted or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, email-client

I have a ruby / rails application that integrates in and outgoing email directly into the app.  The app is going to be running on multiple domains each with posible many users sending and recieving email.

I have looked into sendgrid, mailchimp and mad mimi as hosted services and also looked to create my own email server.

There are advantages and disadvantages of both solutions and i am not sure which one to go down and am hoping someone can give me advice ??

Any help will be great.   I know email is a hassle to manage but once set up correctly cant be that bad ??

Thanks in advance
Rick

Answer (score 0):

Hosting your own Mail Transfer Agent (MTA) has some benefits with easier mailbox creation and less latency but it requires significantly more maintenance.  There's also the problem with spam filtering that would require some constant tweaking.  An outside firm will likely have a more advanced filtering system in place that you can leverage the larger quantity of traffic passing through it.

Never underestimate the increased effort for uptime as more components are integrated.

Comment: think i might setup postfix and resque_mailer.
this tutorial looks good http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/9/2/mail-server-overview
and this one for the rest of spam / virus protection http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/
any comments ??

Comment: Postfix is one of the primary MTAs out there these days.  I actually was going to switch to it myself (from Qmail) but decided against hosting my own for other reasons.  SpamAssassin works well with a good rule set.  I believe I was using Amavisd as well. I was also using Courier for imaps/pop3s and it works very well.

I would probably follow the second tutorial.  The first one doesn't seem to cover adding SpamAssassin.

It's worth looking into cacert.org for a SSL cert instead of self-signing btw.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Heroku, the have some mail add-ons

Comment: the mail add on is sendgrid and it costs 199 dollars a month for multiple domains